# AWS S3 PHP File Upload. Returning URL but not actually uploading

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im using the AWS SDK for php to upload files to my S3 bucket. I've created a separate user using the IAM Manager and have given it Full access to S3. This is the code i've implemented (PHP7, apache2)

```
$bucket = 'bucketname';

$file_path = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$key = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

try{
    //Create a S3Client
    $s3Client = new S3Client([
        'version'     => 'latest',
        'region'      => 'ap-south-1',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => 'my-key',
            'secret' => 'secret-key',
        ],
    ]);

    $result = $s3Client->putObject([
        'Bucket'     => $bucket,
        'Key'        => $key,
        'SourceFile' => $file_path,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ]);

    echo $result['ObjectURL'];
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

On uploading the file i am getting the url back like so

https://bucketname.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/image.png
(Not real URL)

This is the xml response i get back

```
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
    <Key>/image.png</Key>
    <RequestId>E131E328AF9CAF41</RequestId>
    <HostId>gOreLsZBX9V1Whq++BoJVZCKPS415r51IUXXs0zZeIoa16KaXBCzOYKFrYYRktJJBB8HnBSyDTM=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure your S3 client key is correct

Comment: Do you see your file on S3?

Comment: S3 client key is correct. @Thamaraiselvam no it shows the bucket as empty

Comment: @JCDenton 
try the move_upload_file() function instead of putobject()

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the

> move_upload_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $path);

$path is your bucket path

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code.

- You are only catching S3Exceptions. Also catch other exceptions by adding the following code and displaying the error. You will find that your code is generating other errors.

  } catch (Exception $e) { 
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n"; }
- You are missing the cacert.pem file for SSL certificate handling. Download this file from [CA certificates extracted from Mozilla](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) and copy to a directory on your system.
- Modify your PHP.INI file to include cacert.pem using the full path to where your downloaded and installed it. Under the PHP.INI section [openssl], add this line:

  openssl.cafile=/path/cacert.pem